# Logging in into few sites at once

Tags: logging

I've got few sites set up on one server, which are available only for employees.
There is a helpdesk, an intranet site and few others. The sites are standing on different engines, intranet for example is running on joomla. Is this possible in some way that employee logs into one site, and after that is automatically logged into the rest?

We don't have a domain here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is possible...

However, if each site uses a different type of CMS, then you'll need to write code to make all those CMSes accept the credential that another CMS accepted.

So if I log in the Joomla website, when I go to the Drupal website, that second site would need to query Joomla and ask it whether this user is currently logged in. If yes, then simulate a logged in user in Drupal.

This assumes that all your users have the exact same name in all websites too... Otherwise you'll have a bit of a headache.

Now frankly that is going to be a lot of development. However, many systems (like Joomla and Drupal) support external log in (I think it's called OpenID). You could eventually force people to log in through that one external log in system and then let the other services check that one login system. Either way, it's going to be quite a bit of work.

So more or less, yes of course it's possible, whether you'd want to spend the time to make it work, probably not, unless you can use an OpenID mechanism to work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your responsone! Ill check out thath OpenID mechanism as soon as possible.